# Class SymfonyStandard\Composer is not autoloadable

Tags: symfony, curl, composer-php

I've always started new Symfony projects with Composer executing:

`composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name`

until now..

For no apparent reason, Composer started to complain with this error:

> Class SymfonyStandard\Composer is not autoloadable, can not call
>   post-root-package-install script

Has anyone encountered this problem?

I should also add that Composer proceeded with installing the project after displaying this message.

Comment: Yes, but has the `php_curl` extension been enabled?

Comment: @JovanPerovic That was an easy fix.Thank you. I didn't think about that as it was all good with starting SF projects with Composer until now. Nevertheless the first message about "composer not being autoloadable" remains. Any idea what this means and how I could fix it ?

Comment: I've decided to narrow down the question as these are really two separate issues

Comment: Did you try updating the `composer`?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your vendor directory and trying again with your curl extension enabled correctly.

Comment: This answers a previous part of the question, that has been removed since.